# How can I convert this javascript code to Java?

Tags: java, javascript, symbols

I have this code in javascript.

```
symbol = window.prompt( "Enter the symbol", "+" );

    if (symbol == "+")
        {
        result = value1 + value2;
        document.writeln( "<h1>The sum is " + sum + "</h1>" );
        }

     else if (symbol == "-")
        {
        result = value1 - value2;
        document.writeln( "<h1>The sub is " + sum + "</h1>" );
        }

     else if (symbol == "*")
        {
        result = value1 * value2;
        document.writeln( "<h1>The multiplication is " + sum + "</h1>" );
        }

     else if (symbol == "/")
        {
        result = value1 / value2;
        document.writeln( "<h1>The division is " + sum + "</h1>" );
        }
```

I want to convert it in Java.
The user has already input two numbers and now he has to input one of 4 symbols (+, -, *, /) in order to do the additional arithmetical operation and get the result.

Comment: using javaFX or swing?

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am currently using notepad++ and I just want to convert this javascript code into Java.

The thing that I am having trouble with is that I am not that familiar with Java.

Also I do not know to what I have to convert this line symbol = window.prompt( "Enter the symbol", "+" );

Comment: I don't know much about JavaScript, but if I had to guess `window.prompt` would likely be a JDialog popup. Inside the JDialog, you could put a JLabel, JTextField, and JButton for confirmation. Hope this helps to get you started! Alternatively, if you don't want a GUI, you could do this in the command terminal by simply using `System.out.println("Enter the symbol...");`

Comment: That's exactly what the window.prompt does. The only thing that I need is to get the same in Java, even without the JDialog popup. I just want to get the symbol that the user inputs. Well I have 'thisvalue1 = (new Integer(in.readLine())).intValue();' to get the first number from the user, I just do not know how to get the symbol, since it is not an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...)` to simulate `window.prompt()`. The rest is straightforward.

#### Sample code:

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DemoJOptionPane {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double value1 = 5, value2 = 3, result;

        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        String symbol = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "+-*/",
                "Enter the symbol", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        if (symbol.equals("+")) {
            result = value1 + value2;
            System.out.println("<h1>The sum is " + result + "</h1>");
        } else if (symbol.equals("-")) {
            result = value1 - value2;
            System.out.println("<h1>The sub is " + result + "</h1>");
        } else if (symbol.equals("*")) {
            result = value1 * value2;
            System.out.println("<h1>The multiplication is " + result + "</h1>");
        } else if (symbol.equals("/")) {
            result = value1 / value2;
            System.out.println("<h1>The division is " + result + "</h1>");
        }
    }
}
```

---

It may be simpler on your scenario, if you just want the user to type information, you can also ask for input directly in the console.

The sample code below will request for the input in the console and behave the same way as the previous code.

#### Sample code (input from the console):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DemoScanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double value1 = 5, value2 = 3, result;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the symbol (+-*/): ");
        String symbol = in.next().substring(0, 1);
        in.close();

        if (symbol.equals("+")) {
            result = value1 + value2;
            System.out.println("<h1>The sum is " + result + "</h1>");
        } else if (symbol.equals("-")) {
            result = value1 - value2;
            System.out.println("<h1>The sub is " + result + "</h1>");
        } else if (symbol.equals("*")) {
            result = value1 * value2;
            System.out.println("<h1>The multiplication is " + result + "</h1>");
        } else if (symbol.equals("/")) {
            result = value1 / value2;
            System.out.println("<h1>The division is " + result + "</h1>");
        }
    }
}
```